# CSS3 grid 20 в ряд

Tags: css3, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу чтобы в ряд стояло 20 квадратов.

Код не могу вставить, не получается.

Comment: Я просто хочу сделать координатную сетку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я хочу чтобы в ряд стояло 20 квадратов

Просто ряд из 20 блоков с помощью CSS Grid?

Я так понимаю, принципиально, чтобы сохранялись пропорции и они всегда оставались квадратами?

Так?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
}

.item__inner {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! А подскажи, как сделать вертикальный раздел?
https://prnt.sc/p6vfp1

Comment: Вопрос о промежутке между блоками? Он задаётся через свойство `grid-gap:5px` (вместо 5px подставить нужное значение)

Comment: @MrRiseYTMrRise, если ответ помог, просьба пометить его решением. Скриншот галочки отметки: http://bit.ly/2Hss3VA